# Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): in __call__ return self.func(*args) line 1646, in configure

Tags: python, tkinter

I was just checking this code and not able to rectify these kind of errors can anyone help me please
thanks in advance
The program is getting executed and showing the output but after when I cancel, It shows these errors. This is a quiz game, it is also displaying the score as 0 everytime even if the answers are right

```
    def menu():
    menu = Tk()
    menu_canvas = Canvas(menu,width=720,height=440,bg="#101357")
    menu_canvas.pack()
    menu_frame = Frame(menu_canvas,bg="white")
    menu_frame.place(relwidth=0.8,relheight=0.8,relx=0.1,rely=0.1)
    var = IntVar()
    easyR = Radiobutton(menu_frame,text='Easy',bg="white",font="calibri 16",value=1,variable= var,command=easy)
    easyR.place(relx=0.25,rely=0.4)
        def navigate():
            x = var.get()
            print(x)
            if x == 1:
               menu.destroy()
               easy()
             else:
               pass
    letsgo = Button(menu_frame,text="Let's Go",bg="white",font="calibri 12",command=navigate)
    letsgo.place(relx=0.25,rely=0.8)
    menu.mainloop()
    

    def easy():
    global e
    e = Tk()
    easy_canvas = Canvas(e,width=720,height=440,bg="#101357")
    easy_canvas.pack()
    easy_frame = Frame(easy_canvas,bg="white")
    easy_frame.place(relwidth=0.8,relheight=0.8,relx=0.1,rely=0.1)
         def countDown():
           check = 0
           for k in range(20, 0, -1):
           if k == 1:
                check=-1
           timer.configure(text=k)
           easy_frame.update()
           time.sleep(1)
         timer.configure(text="Times up!")
         if check==-1:
            return (-1)
        else:
            return 0
        global score
        score = 0
    
        easyQ = [
                 [
                     "What is Tkinter?",
                     "Guided User Interface",
                     "Function",
                     "Varaible",
                     "None of These" 
                 ] ,

                [
                    "Which of these is a Boolean Value" ,
                    "Enter",
                    "Esc",
                    "True",
                    "None of These"
                ],
               
                [
                    "Which of the following represents the bitwise XOR operator?" ,
                    "&",
                    "!",
                    "^",
                    "|"
                ]
            ]
         answer = [
                "Guided User Interface",
                "True",
                "^"
             ]
         li = ['',0,1,2]
         x = random.choice(li[1:])
    
         ques = Label(easy_frame,text =easyQ[x][0],font="calibri 12",bg="white")
         ques.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.2,anchor=CENTER)

         var = IntVar()
    
         a = Radiobutton(easy_frame,text=easyQ[x][1],font="calibri 10",value=easyQ[x][1],variable = var,bg="white")
         a.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.42,anchor=CENTER)

         b = Radiobutton(easy_frame,text=easyQ[x][2],font="calibri 10",value=easyQ[x][2],variable = var,bg="white")
         b.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.52,anchor=CENTER)

         c = Radiobutton(easy_frame,text=easyQ[x][3],font="calibri 10",value=easyQ[x][3],variable = var,bg="white")
         c.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.62,anchor=CENTER) 

         d = Radiobutton(easy_frame,text=easyQ[x][4],font="calibri 10",value=easyQ[x][4],variable = var,bg="white")
         d.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.72,anchor=CENTER) 
    
        li.remove(x)
    
       timer = Label(e)
       timer.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.82,anchor=CENTER)
    
    
    
      def display():
        
        if len(li) == 1:
                e.destroy()
                showMark(score)
        if len(li) == 2:
            nextQuestion.configure(text='End',command=calc)
                
        if li:
            x = random.choice(li[1:])
            ques.configure(text =easyQ[x][0])
            
            a.configure(text=easyQ[x][1],value=easyQ[x][1])
      
            b.configure(text=easyQ[x][2],value=easyQ[x][2])
      
            c.configure(text=easyQ[x][3],value=easyQ[x][3])
      
            d.configure(text=easyQ[x][4],value=easyQ[x][4])
            
            li.remove(x)
            print(li)
            y = countDown()
            if y == -1:
                display()

            
    def calc():
        global score
        if (var.get() in answer):
            score+=10
        display()
    
    submit = Button(easy_frame,command=calc,text="Submit")
    submit.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.82,anchor=CENTER)
    
    nextQuestion = Button(easy_frame,command=display,text="Next")
    nextQuestion.place(relx=0.87,rely=0.82,anchor=CENTER)
    
    y = countDown()
    if y == -1:
        display()
    e.mainloop()
    
But the program is running, but the score is printed 0



Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\quizgamee\quiz.py", line 400, in calc
    display()
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\quizgamee\quiz.py", line 378, in display
    x = random.choice(li[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\random.py", line 347, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range

  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\quizgamee\quiz.py", line 400, in calc
    display()
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\quizgamee\quiz.py", line 391, in display
    y = countDown()
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\quizgamee\quiz.py", line 300, in countDown
    timer.configure(text=k)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
```

Comment: Please don't share the code in blocks. It is impossible to tell which code belongs where

Comment: I am not able to post that way, All of these def functions are called inside one main def function its in the same order

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code you have posted won't run on it's own, so it's harder to help.

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions in the comments, please provide the full error traceback.

Comment: I have changed it! Is it clear now. can you see why that error is shown?